# how to prevent apache from decoding url?

Tags: apache, urlencode, urldecode

I have a file named A%20B.html in website's root. When I access the file using http://mywebsite.com/A%20B.html, it complains the file is not found. It is because Apache decodes the url to map to the file named "A B.html". How to prevent Apache from doing so such as writing something in .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access that file via `A%2520B.html`. The literal `%` in the name must be escaped.

Comment: The problem is the urls are embedded in other files. I can change neither the urls nor the file names. The only option left for me seems to do some trick to make apache not decode the urls.

Comment: You could simply rename the file on the server from `A%20B.html` to `A B.html`